# Controlling Webgl Mesh Rotation with the camera movement. [three.js]

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am following the tQuery plugins examples and spend some time playing with the rollercoster example. There i tweak some of the code and did manage to add a custom animating object to the scene. Here the camera follows the points in a spline closed path and i hooked the animating object with the camera so that the object also moves with the camera. What i was hoping to achieve is to face the object towards the scene and move it along the camera which gives nice effect as if the object is moving or racing along the path. The object follows the path but it also changes its rotation with the camera as the camera progress. which gives the effect as if the object is falling through the path. What i am trying to say is this:

http://strongcodelabs.com/bird_stackoverflow/index-tube.html

Here you can see what i have done so far.

and here is the code for that:

https://github.com/kshitizrimal/demo_predator/blob/master/examples/index-tube.html

What i would like to achieve is the object always have same oreintation as it follows the path.

like this:
[image]

The object should always have this orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have line `camera.lookAt(point);` , and that exact same instruction could be used for the bird to direction it.

```
bird.lookAt(point);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: oh my god you are a savior, thankyou so much. can you give me any idea about zooming out the bird in the scene??

Comment: Move the camera away from the `point` along the `lookAt` vector?
If this answer solved your problem please accept it.

Comment: i tried adding some number like 100 or 200 to camera.z but it doesn't zoom out the bird. 'point' is a vector how do i like you said move away? i mean to say how to add integer to the 'point' to make the camera move away?